# IntelliJ open project, default path

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-15

Is there a way to set a default path when opening a project?
**(File -> Open)** . It's always pointing out to `X:\Users\\Username`.
I've been googling and looking inside `X:\Users\Username\.IdeaIC15\config\options` for configuration file which could be the case, but found nothing so far. Anyone know where i can change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched for a solution, but there is no easy one in IDEA/Webstorm UI.

You have to edit the `webstorm64.vmoptions`/ `idea64.vmoptions` file (or `webstorm.vmoptions`/ `idea.vmoptions` if you are on a 32bit system).
Add the line

`-Duser.home=YOUR_NEW_DEFAULT_PATH`

The IDE settings folder (e.g. `.WebStorm11`) must be either copied to your new path or imported on first start of IntelliJ/WebStorm.